# Extending SonataUserBundle installed with easy-extends best practice

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have SonataUserBundle installed in src/Application/Sonata/Userbundle with the command:

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
```

Now I want to extend it, what I need to do for the best:

1. Create a new Entity in the namespace AppBundle/Entity which extends BaseUser class (use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;) and set it in config.yml as "user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User"

OR

2. I need to just edit the src/Application/Sonata/UserBundle/Entity/User.php with the new fields I need to add for the users in the admin panel.

Thanks !!!